# Using clamshell MacBook with external monitor with no speakers - will there be sound?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, audio

If I connect my MacBook to a monitor with no speakers, and use it in clamshell (with the lid closed) will there be no sound / volume? Or will any sound be muffled becaused the lid is closed?

How will I hear error noises or new mail sounds or music? Will I also have to buy speakers? Or only buy a monitor with built in speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested. It will play through the speakers with the clamshell closed and is very audible. It does change the sound quality so music might be a bit different <s>(I din't play any music)</s>, but notifications will be easily discernible.

Tried some music and it comes through quite clearly, just a little quieter than with the lid open.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if the MacBook speaker would be disabled when in clamshell - so thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the MacBook lid is not soundproof, you will hear sound with the lid closed in closed clam shell mode.  Will it be muted?  Yes; it's obviously being blocked.  But, will you be prevented from hearing alerts and notifications?  No.

If you are setting up external peripherals, a decent set of speakers isn't out of order.